# Polymer 1.0 Paper-Tabs Are Not Responsive To Content

Tags: polymer

Using Polymer 1.0, the `paper-tab` elements are not responsive to the size of their content/titles. Instead, all the tabs are a fixed size and it looks bad. From what I can tell, the default behavior is for them to be responsive to the title.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>unquote</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-header-panel>
    <paper-toolbar>
        <paper-tabs>
          <paper-tab>
              ABOUT
          </paper-tab>
          <paper-tab>
            <div>
              TOUR SCHEDULE
            </div>
          </paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>
              <div> 
                VIDEOS
              </div>
            </paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>
              <div> 
                HOST
              </div>
            </paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>
              <div> 
                LONG TITLE THIS IS
              </div>
            </paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
    </paper-toolbar>
  </paper-header-panel>
</body>
</script>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the tabs to fit to their content, you can override the default tab flexing:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  paper-tab {
    flex: none;
  }
</style>
```

http://jsbin.com/bizoso/edit?html,output

If you want the tabs to fill the toolbar, you can `class="flex"` to `paper-tabs`.

```
  <paper-tabs class="flex">
```

http://jsbin.com/xevepi/edit?html,output

Comment: Curious...how come `<paper-tabs flex>` didn't work? Any where can I read more about proper layout for ver. 1.0?

Comment: Actually, this didn't fix the issue. https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/issues/37

Comment: I added more info to my answer.

Comment: What does the `is` attribute do? I'm not finding it to easy in the 1.0 documentation.

Comment: It's creates a variation on the native element type which is defined as a custom element. Check the 'Extending Native Elements' section and info about _type extension_ here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/.

Comment: Unfortunately, IE does not show paper-tabs until width is specified

Answer (score 0):

Try importing `iron-flex-layout` (make sure it's in your bower_components folder!) and using the `selected` and `flex` attributes like so:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
...
<paper-tabs scrollable flex>
    <paper-tab>
        ...
    </paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

Comment: No success. `scrollable` is not want I want ether....the header is not supposed to scroll horizontally.

Comment: to add.... With `scrollable` all the tabs are gone and a scrunched `<>` remains for scrolling.